# center text inside TouchableOpacity

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to place a text in the center of a TouchableOpacity, No, I don't want to use <Button with title.
At the moment the only way I could find to center the text is to make it bigger but that's not the solution I'm searching for..

[image: Here is what I got so far]

As you see the text is not placed in the center..
Here is my code, hope you can help.

```
<View style={{padding: 15}}>
<TouchableOpacity
style={styles.button}
<Text style={{color: 'white' ,fontSize: hp('2.2%') ,justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>Post Room</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View> 

button2: {
display: 'flex',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
height: hp('3.5%'),
width: wp('11%'),
borderRadius: 4
},
```

Comment: could you create an expo snack to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I not able reproduce the issue but for your `Text` element, could you try removing the `justifyContent` and `alignItems` and replacing it with `textAlign: 'center'` and `textAlignVertical: 'center'`

Comment: I did, unfortunatly it didn't change anything